# While loop seems to be passing variables inversely from the Boolean condition

Tags: c++, class, while-loop

I've tested so many scenarios and it works without the while loop; but I just cant seem to figure out whats messing it up. if I pick an int in the target range 1-3 it passes and then freezes and i have to ctrl c the program out.

And if I pick a number outside that range it lets it pass in to the while loop and call the function. I'm very confused and this is the first program I've written with classes; so I feel like that probably is the issue.

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Elevator
{
    public:
        void floorControl();
        // Outputs floor actions and lets a user pick a floor number
        int status();
        // outputs floor positon
    private:
        int floorPosition = 1;
};

int main()
{
    Elevator building[3];
    int elevatorSelect;
    cout << "\tElevator Status\n\tA\tB\tC\n" 
     << "\t" << building[0].status() << "\t" << building[1].status()
     << "\t" << building[2].status() << endl
     << "\tWhich elevator do you want (1=A, 2=B, 3=C, or other to exit) ? ";
     cin >> elevatorSelect;
     cout << "\t" << elevatorSelect <<  endl;
    while((elevatorSelect <= 3) && (elevatorSelect >=1));
    {
        building[elevatorSelect-1].floorControl();
        cout << "\tElevator Status\n\tA\tB\tC\n" 
             << "\t" << building[0].status() << "\t" << building[1].status()
             << "\t" << building[2].status() << endl
             << "\tWhich elevator do you want (1=A, 2=B, 3=C, or other to exit) ? ";
        cin >> elevatorSelect;
         cout << "\t" << elevatorSelect <<  endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

void Elevator::floorControl()
{
    int floorSelect;
    if(floorPosition > 1)
    {
        cout << "\tStarting at floor " << floorPosition << endl;
        for(int i=1; i>floorPosition; floorPosition--)
            cout << "\t  Going down - now at floor " << floorPosition-1 << endl;
        cout << "\tStopping at floor " << floorPosition << endl;
    }
    cout << "\tWhich floor do you want? ";
    cin >> floorSelect;
    if ((floorSelect < 1 )|| (floorSelect > 10))
        cout << "\t**You pick up some dust off the wall; you missed**\n";
    else 
    {
        cout << "\tStarting at floor " << floorPosition << endl;
        for (floorSelect; floorSelect > floorPosition; floorPosition++)
            cout << "\t  Going up - now at floor " << floorPosition+1 << endl;
        cout << "\tStopping at floor " << floorPosition << endl;
    }
}

int Elevator::status()
{
    return floorPosition;
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: The `while` statement has an errant `;`.

Comment: Thank you very much! also I read through that link for the "how to debug a program guide" it was very helpful thank you both.